# Limit scope of formatting to within command

Tags: formatting, titles

I wanted to generate a cover page for a tech report and so put the following in my preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coverpage}{\onecolumn \centering \large
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\noindent\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{Logo_black}}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
{\noindent\huge Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}\vspace*{0.8in}\\
{\noindent\Huge \bf \@title}\vspace*{0.3in}\\
{\noindent \@date}\vspace*{0.3in}\\
{\noindent \@author}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
\textit{TR-ID-12-06}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
\noindent\textbf{Abstract}\vspace*{0.1in}\\
\hspace*{0.1in}\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\input{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\setcounter{page}{0}}
\makeatother
```

Then, after `\begin{document}`, I have a `\coverpage`, followed by `\maketitle` and so on. However, now the whole document is formatted as one-column and centered even though my class file configured it to be two-column (and fully justified). Why does this happen and how should I avoid this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  You could try putting a `\begingroup`, at the start of `coverpage`, and an `\endgroup` at the end.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks for the tip. Will keep in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By surrounding the `coverpage` macro with a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` you limit the effect of the macros to be within that scope.

### Notes:

- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text. It is not needed in your document.
- The `[demo]` option was used for [the `graphicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) so as to place a black box where the figure would go for demo purposes, in your real usage (when you actually have the figures available), you need to remove this option.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coverpage}{\begingroup\onecolumn \centering \large
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\noindent\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{Logo_black}}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
{\noindent\huge Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}\vspace*{0.8in}\\
{\noindent\Huge \bf \@title}\vspace*{0.3in}\\
{\noindent \@date}\vspace*{0.3in}\\
{\noindent \@author}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
\textit{TR-ID-12-06}\vspace*{0.4in}\\
\noindent\textbf{Abstract}\vspace*{0.1in}\\
\hspace*{0.1in}\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
%\input{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\setcounter{page}{0}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \title{Title}
    \coverpage
    \lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
 \newcommand{\coverpage}{\onecolumn {\centering \large
                                    %%
```

Start a group to limit the scope of `\centering`

```
\setcounter{page}{0}%
\par}%
```

End the group to stop `\centering` (always make sure that size changing and paragraph formatting commands include a `\par` at the end.

```
\twocolumn
```

start two column

```
}
```

end the command definition

Some unrelated comments, `\noindent` normally has no effect after `\\` and has no real effect in centering as indentation is 0 anyway. It's best to avoid using `\vspace` in horizontal mode, its effects are defined but hard to explain. `\vspace*{0.3in}\\` is better written as `\\[.3in]`

Comment: thanks for your tips. I learnt a lot from this one post.